# Diagonal corner to corner gradient in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I need to have a diagonal gradient from corner to corner in a canvas, not css.

```
Check example : http://jsfiddle.net/58y8b/77/
```

The first box is fine, since it's a square the gradient coordinates are just top left and bottom right.
Is there a way to calculate those coordinates for the next 2 rectangles so they get the gradient from corner to corner like the first box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fitting a gradient to 4 corners of Rectangle

This can be done with a little trig.

**The solution**

The diagram shows what needs to be done.

[image]

We need to find the coords of point **E** and **D**

We have the rectangle (assume the top left is at (0,0) that has width and height **W**, **H**. We find the angle **pheta** (bottom left) which is the same angle as **pheta** on the bottom right. We need the length of the line **AB** which is part of a right triangle that we have the hypot **H** for and the angle **pheta**. So **AB** is `H * cos(pheta)`. We then get the vector at 90 deg of the diagonal line, and set its length to **AB** then find the center **C** and subtract the vector to get **E** and add the vector to the center **C** for **D**

To find the angle for the diagonal line use `Math.atan2(-H,W)`.

**The code**

The code for it is taken from the fiddle you supplied and for `rect4`

```
//==========================================================
// NOTE this assumes that the top left of rect is at (0,0)
// if it is not then add the top left coordinate to the
// coordinates of E and D when defining the gradient position
// all else is the same
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// get angle from bottom left to top right
var pheta = Math.atan2(-rect4.height,rect4.width);
// get the length of the line from bottom right to diagonal line
// we got the ang of.
var AB = Math.abs(rect4.height * Math.cos(pheta)); // dont need the abd but cant be bothered
                                                 // explaining why its negative 
// get vector at 90 deg from found angle
var xdx = Math.cos(pheta + Math.PI/2);
var xdy = Math.sin(pheta + Math.PI/2);
// from the center C of rectangle move AB dist back and forward to find
// points E and D
var x1 = rect4.width/2 - xdx * AB;
var y1 = rect4.height/2 - xdy * AB;
var x2 = rect4.width/2 + xdx * AB;
var y2 = rect4.height/2 + xdy * AB;
// Now create the gradient from E to D
rect4.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: x1,
    y1: y1,
    x2: x2,
    y2: y2,
    colorStops: gradient
});
```

**The result**

The image need no words..

[image]

Comment: Thx! We came up with a solution that gave the same result ( or one coordinate differed by 0.000000000000004 ):



`function getCoordsForDiagonalGradient (width, height) {
        var alfa = Math.atan(height / width);
        var x = Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height) / 2 / (Math.cos(alfa));
        var z = ((width - x) * Math.cos(alfa)) * Math.sin(Math.PI/2 - alfa);
        var w = ((width - x) * Math.cos(alfa)) * Math.cos(Math.PI/2 - alfa);  
        return {
            x1: z,
            y1: -w,
            x2: width - z,
            y2: w + height
        }
    }
`